# Ignore invisible field validation during form data submit

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a form panel having fields like textfield and radio buttons.There are some conditions to hide textfield as per the radio button value.

have added custom validation to textfield.Suppose i have enter a invalid value to a text filed, then i clicked the radio button. as per my condition that invalid text field is now invisible.

Except that invisible field all other fields are valid. Now i want to submit the form data.

Is it possible to ignore the invisible field while submitting the form panel data.?

Thanks

Comment: if you don't put them name attributes then they will not be included in the form data.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña This is not true, the fields get look uppped via the name property or the id property. To prevent a field from submit set `submitValue: false`. And if you have a custom validation then it would work if you simply return true if the field is hidden

Answer (score 0):

Set the field not only to `hidden` as also to `disabled`, that will solve this. Or as mentioned in the comment if you just use a custom validation return true.